# Div beneath another div and to show with transitions on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to achieve something that look simple but I am not able to find a solution.
I have something like this

```
           <main>
              <div class="prod_container">
                <div class="prod_box box1">
                    <img alt="product" src="images/prod1.png">
                    <h3>bibendum nec</h3>
                    <div class="prod_text hidden">
                        <p>Der neue bibendum nec nunc eleifend, posuere facilisis mi Jeep</p>
                        <a class="prod_button" href="#">More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prod_box box2">
                    <img alt="product" src="images/prod2.png">
                    <h3>condimentum dapibus</h3>
                    <div class="prod_text hidden">
                        <p>Der neue bibendum nec nunc eleifend, posuere facilisis mi Jeep</p>
                        <a class="prod_button" href="#">More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prod_box box3">
                    <img alt="product" src="images/prod3.png">
                    <h3>facilisis purus</h3>
                    <div class="prod_text hidden">
                        <p>Der neue bibendum nec nunc eleifend, posuere facilisis mi Jeep</p>
                        <a class="prod_button" href="#">More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <main>
<footer></footer>
```

and CSS

```
    .prod_box { float:left; width:300px; border:2px solid #cccccc; margin:0 10px 0; position:relative;}
    .prod_box img { float:left; width:100%;}
    .prod_text { width:100%; float:left; border-top:none; padding:10px;}
    footer { float:left; width:100%; background-color:#fedf46; padding:20px 0; z-index:999; clear:both;}
```

Here what I want achieve is that, class .prod_text must go beneath footer for all three boxes on load and when hover on class .prod_box .prod_text must slide up to show. But when I did, the border for .prod_box and the .prod_text shows over footer, and the img goes beneath the footer (I applied position:relative; and bottom:-100px;)

I need an effect like we pick a card from its stack.

Please go through this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=VptJurBM6I)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your javascript code.

Comment: @VaibhavKatole I didn't added any js till now as I dont know how to make that div go beneath footer with css styling. Please help

Comment: this is not the way to ask question on SO plz show some code you have tried so far..

Comment: sorry for that, I am first to stackoverflow.

Comment: @CodeName44 you should not expect people to do all task for you. Instead you should try something yourself and let us know if you stuck somewhere in process.

Comment: plz visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry,@Kartikeya, @VaibhavKatole, Thanks for the link, and I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this??

### HTML

```
<ul class="prod_list">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/yamaha_r6_bike-HD.jpg" alt="Bike 01" /><span>Yamaha Bike 01</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://hdnewwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bmw-hd-race-bike-wallpapers.jpg" alt="Bike 02" /><span>Yamaha Bike 02</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bike-wallpaper-12.jpg" alt="Bike 03" /><span>Yamaha Bike 03</span></a></li>    
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px; color:#333;}
ul, li{list-style:none;}
.prod_list{margin:10px;}
.prod_list li a{width:135px; height:135px; margin:0 12px 12px 0; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block; padding:2px; border:2px solid #ddd; position:relative; float:left;}
.prod_list li a img{width:135px; height:135px; overflow:hidden;}
.prod_list li a span{width:125px; position:absolute; margin-bottom:-25px; bottom:0; left:2px; background:url('http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/transpBlack25.png') 0 0 repeat; color:#fff; line-height:18px; padding:5px 5px 0;}
.prod_list li a:hover{border:2px solid #bbb;}
.prod_list li a:hover span{display:block;}
```

### Javascript (Don't forget to mention JQuery 1.6.x or above)

```
    $('.prod_list li a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find("span").animate({marginBottom:"2px"},"fast");
    });
    $('.prod_list li a').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find("span").animate({marginBottom:"-25px"},"fast");
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/am3j3Lyw/)

Comment: Thank you @KarthikN But how to make that .prod_text div hide beneath footer?, means the second part of each of .prod_box must hide behind footer. that is the prime problem I am facing. And more than that, here text is showing on hover. But what I want to achieve is, when hover on prod_box, it must slide up to display prod_text, like we pick a card from its stack.

Comment: Check the same fiddle link

Comment: I heve added the fiddle link [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=VptJurBM6I). Please go through that, where i tried what to achieve but in vain.

Comment: come to chat for that fiddle link you provide